# Overflow-x appearing but cannot scroll

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have Created a table with fixed header but the problem is that when i have min-width on the container no overflow-x appearing but i cannot adjust the width for the content because i needed them to have fixed width that's why i put the container to have minimum width. I have attached a fiddle sample this is the reference i was following.
[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/pynechan/cb1r6pzg/1/)

```css
table{
  width:100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.tbl-header{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 }
.tbl-content{
  height:300px;
  overflow-x:auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
th{
  padding: 20px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
td{
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}


/* demo styles */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,300,700);
body{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #25c481, #25b7c4);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #25c481, #25b7c4);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
section{
  margin: 50px;
}


/* follow me template */
.made-with-love {
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #fff;
}
.made-with-love i {
  font-style: normal;
  color: #F50057;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}
.made-with-love a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.made-with-love a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/* for custom scrollbar for webkit browser*/

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
} 
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
} 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
}

section{
  min-width:1300px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="tbl-header">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Code</th>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Change</th>
          <th>Change %</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="tbl-content">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>


<!-- follow me template -->
<div class="made-with-love">
  Made with
  <i>♥</i> by
  <a target="_blank" href="https://codepen.io/nikhil8krishnan">Nikhil Krishnan</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give `min-width: 1300px;` to .tbl-header , .tbl-content instead of section, and you're done!!

```css
table{
  width:100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.tbl-header{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 }
.tbl-content{
  height:300px;
  overflow-x:auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
th{
  padding: 20px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
td{
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}


/* demo styles */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,300,700);
body{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #25c481, #25b7c4);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #25c481, #25b7c4);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
section{
  margin: 50px;
}


/* follow me template */
.made-with-love {
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #fff;
}
.made-with-love i {
  font-style: normal;
  color: #F50057;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}
.made-with-love a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.made-with-love a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/* for custom scrollbar for webkit browser*/

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
} 
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
} 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
}

section{
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
.tbl-header , .tbl-content {
    min-width: 1300px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="tbl-header">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Code</th>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Change</th>
          <th>Change %</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="tbl-content">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>


<!-- follow me template -->
<div class="made-with-love">
  Made with
  <i>♥</i> by
  <a target="_blank" href="https://codepen.io/nikhil8krishnan">Nikhil Krishnan</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your css like this :

```css
.tbl-header{
  min-width:1300px; /* add this line */
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 }

.tbl-content{
  min-width:1300px; /* add this line */
  height:300px;
  overflow-x:auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

section{
  /* min-width:1300px; remove this line */
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

Check here : https://jsfiddle.net/3w4j8q16/